# How are P, R, and F scores calculated in spaCy CLI train NER?

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am using the spaCy CLI train command for NER with `train_path` set to the training dataset (train-set) and  `dev_path` set to the evaluation dataset (test-set). The printout in the console shows me NER Precision, Recall, and the F-score.

However, it is not clear to me how the scores were calculated. Are they the scores from the model predicting on the train-set (train-scores) or from the test-set (test-scores)?

I want to determine after which epoch to stop training to prevent overfitting. Currently after 60 epochs the Loss is still slightly decreasing and Precision, Recall, and F-score are still slightly increasing. It seems to me that the model might be memorizing the training data and that the P, R, and F-scores are calculated on the train-set and thus keep improving.

To my knowledge a good stopping point in training would be right before the test-scores start dropping again, even though the train-scores keep increasing. So I would like to compare them over time (epochs).

My questions are:

1. Are the scores displayed in the console while training train-scores or test-scores?
2. And how to get access to the other one?
3. If it is the train-score, for what is the testset (`dev_path`) used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `loss` is calculated from the training examples, as a side effect of calling `nlp.update()` in the [training loop](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/cli/train.py#L425). However, all the other performance metrics are calculated on the dev set, by [calling](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/cli/train.py#L463) the `Scorer`.

> To my knowledge a good stopping point in training would be right before the test-scores start dropping again, even though the train-scores keep increasing

Yep, I agree. So looking at the `spacy train` results, this would be when the (training) loss is still decreasing, while the (dev) F-score starts decreasing again.

> Currently after 60 epochs the Loss is still slightly decreasing and Precision, Recall, and F-score are still slightly increasing.

So it looks like you can train for some epochs more :-)